# Link .so file into an executable file

Tags: c, makefile, linker, shared-libraries, clang

I have object code that I have compiled using -fPIC switch in clang that also used the -shared switch. I have then linked all of these into a single .so shared object. Now I want to link this into a single executable file, I'm told by the man page that I should be able to do this using the 
`ld` command and the -l switch. But when I do this, I get the following error:

```
ld -r -L./ -l:libmymath.so simpleone
ld: attempted static link of dynamic object `libmymath.so'
make: *** [simpleone] Error 1
```

I have tried doing the same thing with the -dy switch, but it gives me the same error.
I really don't understand why this wouldn't be working.

Here is the makefile I am using to do all of this.

```
CC= clang 
LD= ld -r
CFLAGS= -std=gnu99 -g -Oz -c 
CSECFL= -fPIC -I -L 
CFLAG3= -shared
RM= /bin/rm -f
OBJ= math.o my*.o
SO= libmymath.so

all: math my_add my_mul 

math: math.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $@.c $(CSECFL)

my_add: my_add.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $@.c $(CSECFL)

my_mul: my_mul.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $@.c $(CSECFL)

simplemath: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(OBJ) -o $@ 

simplemath.o: $(OBJ)
    $(LD) $(OBJ) -o $@

lib1: my_add.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAG3) my_add.o -o $(SO)

lib2: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAG3) my_mul.o -o $(SO)

lib3: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAG3) math.o -o $(SO)

simpleone: $(OBJ)
    $(LD) -L./ -l:libmymath.so $@

clean:
    $(RM) *.o simplemath* *.t $(SO)
```

Comment: You should use $(CC) for linking.

Comment: Using $(CC) gives me <br>
`clang  -l:libmymath.so -o simpleone
libmymath.so: undefined reference to `int_mul'
libmymath.so: undefined reference to `int_add'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [simpleone] Error 1`
<br>

I don't understand why it says undefined references, I linked the multiply and add in lib1 and lib2.

Comment: Makefile is completely messed up. From which file .so created - my_add.o, my_mul.o or math.o? In theory - from them all, but it isn't what you've written.

Comment: All three of them, I run lib1 then lib2 and finally lib3. This will relink (or rebuild) the .so file each time, won't it?

Comment: No, it will overwrite .so with new result each time.

Comment: So I need all three of the .o files under one target then?

Comment: `$(CC) -shared -fPIC my_add.c my_mul.c math.c -o $(SO)`. Better write correct makefile that handles .o files separately, though (linking .o's into .so, with correct dependency list).

Comment: The new targets rule is `lib: $(OBJ)
 $(CC) $(CFLAG3) $(OBJ) -o $(SO)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link the objects (*.o) into a static executable, not the shared lib (.so)  .so can be opened by the run-time dynamic linker or via a dlopen() call.

Comment: This doesn't help me at all. I need to link them into a .so file because I am going to be using these lib files later on in multiple files and I want to know why this won't work.

Comment: It won't work because the information needed to link them into a static executable is no longer present in a .so, it just can't be done.

You can certainly create both a shared library for run-time programs to use, and a set of objects with the same code, to link statically.
Why or in what way does needing to "use these lib files later on in multiple files" prevent you from linking objects into static binaries?

Comment: To be clear - the -l option to ld will load .so symbols, but it's for linking other shared libraries, not doing a static link.

You can happily build both an .so for run-time usage and .o for static linking (these usually get archived with ar into a .a), however.   You don't have to "choose" between them.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you're saying.  I can't use a .so file to make an executable file? I'm working under the assumption that something like step 4 [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html) works. I know I don't have to choose between them, but I'm trying to create a dynamic runtime library that I can re-use. 

I think I'm just not understanding how I can use a dynamic library with an executable.

Comment: An .so *is* a dynamic library!  It is for linking at run-time, by a running executable.  (Step 4 in your link is just telling the dynamic, run-time linker where the .so is on the filesystem)

"Statically linked" here means "no run-time, .so library is required".
An .a is a static library, an ar archive of objects.   It is for linking at compile-time, statically.

Comment: Have anyone said linking needs to be static? I don't see it.

Comment: He sure does.   Read the question... he makes the .so, then he wants to "link it into a single executable": ie. static linking of a .so into a single executable.   That can't be done.  You link the .o into a single executable, not the .so.

Comment: If I understand correctly, a .so can't be used by an ELF file, because the .so is dynamic, and the executable is static?

Comment: Not how I see it, so not 'sure'. Following that logic will also require stripping off libc and dynamic linker itself. Description isn't very clear of course.

Comment: @user54590 no it can, but your elf will require .so to be present when it runs.

Comment: Further, he's trying to use -l because he read it takes a .so as an input.   So, needed to explain the difference between static linkage and dynamic.

Comment: `-l` don't really cares if library is static or dynamic. But - doesn't matter now.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand, I can use the .so for run time things, but I have to tell the executable explicitly to use the .so at run time, otherwise it will try to use it statically, which it can't do.

Comment: Thank you BadZen and keltar; After telling it explicitly to use the .so at run time only, it worked. Also changing that makefile rule to use $(OBJ) under one target helped out.